# Not able to set value for standard field via force:inputfield

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

We are setting value `force:inputField` for Account Lookup field on Opportunity object for Lightning Component.

```
component.set("v.newOpportunity.AccountId", accountDetailsId);

// we need this for the actual 'pill' in the lookup field
var values = [{
    type: 'Account',
    id: accountDetailsId,
    label: component.get('v.account.Name'),
    icon : {
        url:'/img/icon/t4v35/standard/account_120.png',
        backgroundColor:'A094ED',
        alt:'Account'
    }
}];

component.find("accountName").get("v.body")[0].set("v.values", values);
```

Do we have any other workaround for this? 
Even after setting value, I am getting undefined for following code.

```
component.find("accountName").get("v.body")[0].get("v.values")
```

Component side code:

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label"
            for="accountName">Account Name: </label>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">     
        <force:inputField aura:id="accountName" value="{!v.newOpportunity.AccountId}" required="true"/>
    </div>
</div>
```